# Is this logic gate circuit equivalent to the Simulink model?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Is this Simulink model

[image]

equivalent to this circuit?

[image]

Although the circuit simulated in Multisim works exactly the same as the Simulink model, switching (S1) between 5v and 0V causes an error. I guess this is a bug with the software because the output is identical to the Simulink model when a switch is not used.

Also, is it possible to eliminate any of these components as I will need 20 of these circuits in the final product. Note, I know that the top case is not achievable in this configuration. This will be needed in the final circuit as A can be HIGH or LOW instead of LOW only.

**----- EDIT -----**

I found out that the logic gates in MultiSim are not operating as anticipated and I replaced them with logic gate ICs. This is a shame on NI. The result is exactly the same as the Simulink model. The final circuit is as follows:

[image]
[image]

**----- APPENDIX -----**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is really connected at input A? It's not really connected directly to ground, is it?

Comment: think about the output of the switch when you flip it

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, it is. The buffer outputs Digital 1V and the inverter outputs Digital 0V.

Comment: If the input to U7A is ground then the output of U9A is 1 and the output of U1A is 0 so the output of U2A must be 0...something looks fishy. Why do you have the 7407 at all, it provides no logical function? Perhaps it is not modeled correctly without a pullup?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I solved it. Please see my edit.

Comment: Was your problem that the 7407 needs a pullup to work correctly in Multisim?

Comment: Agree with @ElliotAlderson - there was no need to go to a chip/pin level implementation, the problem was almost certainly the use of the unnecessary open collector buffers which didn't feature in either the original circuit or the final version.

Comment: @Jules I agree that there is no need for the buffer and in fact I didn't use them in my initial design. But without the buffers the simulation was not working in the same way as the Simulink model. See the visuals in the appendix - you will realize that the outcome is the same as the final version of the circuit that doesn't use any buffers.

Comment: 74xx07 is almost never what you want to use.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Do you have any replacement suggestions?

Comment: No, because buffer gates are almost never used in such a casual context.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am not using any buffer gates in my final design???